# Is there a way to say ∃! in prolog?

Tags: prolog, boolean, boolean-logic, boolean-expression

In prolog, is there a way to say "there exists exactly one" (`∃!`)?
I was thinking about doing something like

```
% a predicate which is proven true if there is only one tall person
only_one_tall() :- is_tall(X), is_tall(Y), X\=Y.
```

and then negating the whole thing.
But I don't think this works.

Does anyone know?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to produce a condition like that in standard Prolog is as follows:

```
only_one_tall() :- findall(X, is_tall(X), List), length(List, 1).
```

Here is a [demo on ideone](http://ideone.com/zkSpuO).